# Google workspace account has been suspended with no recovery method

Tags: email, gmail, hosting

This question is how to get support from a huge technology company that sells tech services [Google Workspace (aka gSuite)] when they have locked your account despite you having the proper credentials.

Many years ago I set up my domain so Google would manage my domain's email.  Today, possibly because I was accessing from another state, Google decides to suspend the service:

> Your organization's Google workspace account has been suspended. Please contact your Google workspace organization administrator to re-activate your organization.

So since I'm the administrator, I try to logon with those credentials, which are correct, but they challenge me, and want me to complete an email loop, but **the recovery email is in the locked domain!**

There seems to be no way to get this fixed. There's some code they can send me that I'm supposed to put my domain's server to prove I'm legit, but Google controls that...I have nothing on the domain except email. I'm paying Hover as the registrar.

Any way out?

ETA: I appreciate **"Only Google can help"**, but there's no path forward. No phone number, no button to "open a ticket", no live chat. How would a superuser get through on a problem like this?

There is a page that says:

> To get phone, chat, or email support for your legacy free account at xxxxxxx.com, you need to upgrade to Google Workspace.

> To continue, switch to an administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.

https://support.google.com/a

But I can't log in as administrator to upgrade my account so I can get support because when I log in with correct credentials, they send a challenge to an email address that's in the locked domain!

I can't be the only one this happened to, so figure they're just hiding the path to victory so they don't have to answer too many phone calls.  This page might be as close as I've gotten: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6335621

When I try to open a support case under my non-admin account, it says

> You do not have permission to create support cases.

ETA2: I found a form to fill out: https://support.google.com/accounts/contact/disabled2

## Solved

Google sends an email with a code. They ask you to put that in a CNAME and/or TXT record in DNS. I didn't know what that meant, but learned, as follows.

My domain registrar, Hover, did what was required. I logged into my Hover account, pasted the email from Google into a chat, and they knew what to do.

I went back to the Google email, clicked the link, hit 'try again' on the DNS thing, and I got to a 'reset your password' screen. This was **the goal** of this question.

The bottom line is that whoever you pay to get your domain... That's who can update DNS to prove to Google that *it's really you* trying to log in.

Comment: Only Google can help you with this. But I don’t believe this is the cause, “ Today, possibly because I was accessing from another state, Google decides to suspend the service.” The whole idea of a Google workspace is that it can be accessed anywhere. _Maybe_ this login triggered a process, but the reality is something else has happened here. Only Google can help.

Comment: @John Certainly only Google can help. The question is HOW to get Google to help. There must be an avenue, but I can't find it. If how to get support from a company isn't an appropriate question for this stackexchange, I'll try another.

Comment: Superuser isn't Google support. It doesn't matter how large the company is, Superuser isn't official support for them.

Comment: @music2myear I agree 100% Superuser isn't Google support. Question is closed, and that's fine, but to be clear, the question was how to get access to support at Google, not asking for members here to stand in for Google. Thanks.